# Javascript Object within Object get property

Tags: javascript, json, object

Been searching for an hour or o and can't find what I'm looking for.  Any help appreciated.

I have a JSON object coming from an ajax call that contains a couple of other objects with numerical keys.

Eg.

```
{"1" : { "Name" : "George", "DOB" : "11/1/88", "NickName" : "Porky" },
"2" : { "Name" : "Pete", "DOB" : "6/6/85", "NickName" : "Bozo" }}
```

I now want to access the properties in these object independently.  For example:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    alert(obj. something here .Name);
}
```

But I can't for the life of me find the right syntax.  I have tried...

obj.1.Name (I've seen this where the key of each object is a string but not a number)

and...

```
obj[1].Name
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery?  How can I say, create an array of `[Name1, Name2, etc...]`?

Comment: `obj[key].Name` because of your `for...in` statement, `key` is the "name" of each property.

Comment: var obj = {"1" : { "Name" : "George", "DOB" : "11/1/88", "NickName" : "Porky" },
"2" : { "Name" : "Pete", "DOB" : "6/6/85", "NickName" : "Bozo" }};
alert(obj['1']['Name']);

Comment: Cerbrus.  That question doesn't deal with an object within an object, simply an object with properties inside.  Hence the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for brackets notation:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    alert(obj[key].Name);
}
```

In JavaScript, you can access an object property using either dot notation and a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`), or brackets notation and a *string** property name (`obj["foo"]`). In brackets notation, the string can be from any expression, including a variable lookup.

**Live Example:**

```js
var obj = {
  "1": {
    "Name": "George",
    "DOB": "11/1/88",
    "NickName": "Porky"
  },
  "2": {
    "Name": "Pete",
    "DOB": "6/6/85",
    "NickName": "Bozo"
  }
};
for (var key in obj) {
  snippet.log(obj[key].Name);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

* In ES6 brackets notation will also support `Symbol` property names.

Comment: Tried that and it failed but at least I know I'm using the right syntax and the error might be somewhere else.  Thanks.

Comment: @Barbs: Did you parse the JSON? Remember that JSON is text that describes an object tree. A lot of people *say* JSON when they don't really mean it, but if you're getting back a string, you'll want to run it through `JSON.parse` to get the object tree.

Comment: Hi,  yes I am parsing the JSON. I found the solution by using obj.LastName.  I didn't need the first numerical key because I had already run that through the for loop.  Thanks for all the down votes (not targeted at you TJ).    It amazes me how this question can be marked as a duplicate less than a minute after it was posted.  Surely there needs to be time to read BOTH questions before that happens.  oh well.